# How can i remove the permission on denied folder?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, special-folders

```
private bool GrantAccess(string fullPath)
{
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
        return true;
}
```

Am using this method for remove the denied permission but its not working, please if any help to fix this.

Comment: You should run your application as administrator! And if you are debugging, simply run visual studio as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace FileSystemExample
{
    class DirectoryExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                string DirectoryName = "TestDirectory";

                Console.WriteLine("Adding access control entry for " + DirectoryName);

                // Add the access control entry to the directory.
                AddDirectorySecurity(DirectoryName, @"MYDOMAIN\MyAccount", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);

                Console.WriteLine("Removing access control entry from " + DirectoryName);

                // Remove the access control entry from the directory.
                RemoveDirectorySecurity(DirectoryName, @"MYDOMAIN\MyAccount", FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow);

                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // Adds an ACL entry on the specified directory for the specified account. 
        public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
        {
            // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

            // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the  
            // current security settings.
            DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

            // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
            dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                            Rights,
                                                            ControlType));

            // Set the new access settings.
            dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

        }

        // Removes an ACL entry on the specified directory for the specified account. 
        public static void RemoveDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
        {
            // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

            // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the  
            // current security settings.
            DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

            // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
            dSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                            Rights,
                                                            ControlType));

            // Set the new access settings.
            dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

        }
    }
}
```

more information here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

make sure your application run in high privilege